# Find the type of a non-type template parameter, based on a template class

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Given a class of the form:

```
template <int A, int B, int C>
struct Functor {
  static int go() {
    return A*B*C;
  }
};
```

I need to produce a parameter pack / tuple / etc of the *types* of the parameters for Functor. That is, I want to be able to do things like:

```
// Imagining that I have many Functor classes...
using FirstArgType = TypeAt<Functor, 1>::T;
FirstArgType t {4};
```

Essentially, I need to go from a parameter pack of values, to a parameter pack of the TYPES of those values of an *unspecialized* template class - that is, `Functor` and not `Functor<1, 2, 3>`. I naively starting with things that looked like:

```
template <template <auto...Values> typename Class>
struct ClassInfo {
   using Tuple = std::tuple<decltype(Values)...>;
};
```

However, nested template-template parameters can't be accessed like this (`error: use of undeclared identifier 'Values'`). Note that when I use `auto...Values` as top-level template parameters, this tuple technique works fine to discover the types - the problem is in extracting the template params for `Class`.

For every formulation I've tried, I need to *at some* point specify a fully specialized type (e.g. `Functor<1, 2, 3>`) in order to figure out the types - but I am trying to operate on the *template class* Functor, not the specialization of it `Functor<n,n,n>` - I need template code to operate on *every* specialization, e.g. `Functor<1, 2, 3>` and `Functor<4, 5, 6>`, not just find the types of a specific specialization.

On one hand: I feel like I'm attempting something fundamentally impossible with C++ templates - in way that I don't understand - which is why every formulation I can think of fails.

On the other hand: CLEARLY the types of the template params for `Functor` are well-known at compile time, so I imagine there SHOULD be a way to discover these.

A solution would be great, but I'm equally happy to hear about strategies/techniques/design patterns for dealing with template-template parameters that I'm not familiar with (I wouldn't consider myself a pro here).

Comment: For context: I'm using techniques from the wonderful Petra library (https://github.com/jacquelinekay/petra) to construct switch tables to map runtime values to different compile time specialization a function. So, the pragmatic goal is to call functor<1, 2, 3> with runtime values e.g. mapped_functor(1, 2, 3)

Answer (score 3):

> Essentially, I need to go from a parameter pack of values, to a
> parameter pack of the TYPES of those values.

You can use template partial specialization to extract the type of non-type template parameter, something like this:

```
#include <tuple>

template<auto... args>
struct Functor {};

template <class>
struct ClassInfo {};

template <auto... args>
struct ClassInfo<Functor<args...>> {
  using type = std::tuple<decltype(args)...>;
};

using F = Functor<0, 42u, 'a', true>;
static_assert(
  std::is_same_v<ClassInfo<F>::type, std::tuple<int, unsigned, char, bool>>);
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/e34zvKTT5)

Comment: Good answer, I arrived at something like this myself, but it doesn't exactly solve the problem. This requires that you can refer to a fully specialized `Functor`, e.g. `Functor<0, 42u, 'a', true>` to find the types - I want to operate on the template class `template<int, int, int> Functor` - I want to write code for every possible specialization of `Functor` generically.
I updated my question slightly - *hopefully* it's a little clearer, I feel like I'm not quite using the terminology around template class parameters like `template< <...> typename c>` correctly.

Comment: @scztt  This is impossible since the scope of `auto... Values` in template template parameters are limited to the `Functor` template, and we cannot extract its information from the outside, only the compiler knows it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```cpp
#include <tuple>

template <auto... Values>
struct GenericFunctor {
    using Tuple = std::tuple<decltype(Values)...>;
};

using SpecificFunctor = GenericFunctor<short(1), long(2)>;

// Extracts specific template types from functors.
template<class Functor, int i>
using ArgType = decltype(std::get<i>( std::declval<typename Functor::Tuple>() ));

// Instantiate the specific arg type.
static ArgType<SpecificFunctor, 1> t { 1 };
```